# Using Tango3DR_AreaDescription_createFromDataset on Asus Zenfone AR

Tags: android, c++, google-project-tango

I am creating meshes from Tango datasets, trying to support Asus Zenfone AR. My app is already working fine on Lenovo Phab 2 Pro.

The first step is calling `Tango3DR_AreaDescription_createFromDataset` to create a `Tango3DR_AreaDescription`. I am calling the function without specifying a `loop_closure_database_path` in the second argument:

```
  Tango3DR_Status res = Tango3DR_AreaDescription_createFromDataset(dataset_path.c_str(),
                                                                   nullptr, //loop_closure_database_path
                                                                   &area_description_raw,
                                                                   progress_logger,
                                                                   &num_api_calls);
```

The Zenfone AR crashes in this function, probably related to this logcat line:
`A/tango: loop_closure_file_reader_disk.cc:186 Check failed: generic::DirectoryExists(loop_closure_files_path) Provided root path for loop-closure files /sdcard/config does not exist.`

If I specify an empty (but existing) directory for `loop_closure_database_path`, I get a similar crash:
`A/tango: loop_closure_file_reader_disk.cc:293 Check failed: generic::DirectoryExists(descriptor_sub_path) Path for feature-descriptor type /sdcard/testing/lens_invariant_ocvfreak does not exist.`

Interestingly, I see that my Phab 2 Pro actually has a directory named `/sdcard/config` including various files and a `lens_invariant_ocvfreak` sub-directory. This directory is not present on my Asus Zenfone AR, however.

What can I do to get this working? The documentation in `tango_3d_reconstruction.h` says loop closure database is downloadable from the Tango developers website, but I can't find it anywhere. I am not entirely sure what is loop closure database is actually supposed to do, but there should be a way to manage without it, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New version of library uploaded on https://developers.google.com/tango/downloads which contains the missing file.