# Using Tango3DR_updateFromTrajectoryAndDataset on Asus Zenphone

Tags: android, c++11, google-project-tango

This is a issue similar to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45594520/2713641), but this time, it fails when calling the function:

```
Tango3DR_updateFromTrajectoryAndDataset(context_server,
                                        dataset_path,
                                        trajectory,
                                        NULL,
                                        NULL);
```

This function returns -3 (`TANGO_3DR_ERROR`), and we get the following errors:

```
E/tango: server.cc:79 Dataset has no point clouds.
E/tango: stamped_transform_dataset_player.cc:113 Consumer rejected dataset playback.
```

This error does not occur when running the exact same code with the Lenovo Phab2Pro.

For info:

We store the dataset to the path `/storage/emulated/0/<some folder>/`
and whith `adb shell` into the directory, we can see that the dataset is present.
Prior to calling `Tango3DR_updateFromTrajectoryAndDataset` we call :

```
// the below functions returns TANGO_3DR_SUCCESS
Tango3DR_Status res = Tango3DR_AreaDescription_createFromDataset(dataset_path.c_str(),"/sdcard/loop_closure_database", &area_description, NULL, NULL);
res = Tango3DR_Trajectory_createFromAreaDescription(area_description, &trajectory);
```

to get the trajectory.

Also, we configure the context_server with 
 `TANGO_3DR_CONFIG_RECONSTRUCTION`

Is there anything we need to do differently when setting up the dataset recording on the ASUS? Not sure if this problem is only related to reading the dataset, or if something went wrong when writing to it.